# Tweepy stream.filter documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

```
stream.filter(follow, track, async, locations, stall_warnings, languages, encoding, filter_level)
```

How do I use these streaming options:
- follow
- track
- async
- locations
- stall_warnings
- languages
- encoding
- filter_level

I've searched everywhere but I haven't found anything. I know there's a closed thread over here about the same thing, but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 4):

I have used only a few of these parameters, so I am suggesting the ones that I know.

**track** searches for tweets with specific keywords. These keywords can be specified in the following way.

```
#This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'java'
stream.filter(track=['python', 'java'])
```

**locations** parameter can be used to obtained tweets from a bounding box, like I did. Note that the stream returns tweets if the coordinates field is populated or if coordinates is empty but place is populated. Details can be found in https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters.

```
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(locations = [144.9385,-37.8246,144.9761,-37.7955])
```

I hope you can get an idea now about how to use the other parameters by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The best place is the documentation. The 3rd hit on google for 'tweepy stream filter' gave me

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter.html in particular.

That describes each of the filter options:

> follow    optional    A comma separated list of user IDs, indicating the users to return statuses for in the stream. See follow for more information.
>
> track     optional>   Keywords to track. Phrases of keywords are specified by a  comma-separated list. See track for more information.
>
> locations     optional    Specifies a set of bounding boxes to track. See locations
> for more information.
>
> delimited     optional    Specifies whether messages should be length-delimited. See delimited for more information.
>
> stall_warnings    optional    Specifies whether stall warnings should be
> delivered. See stall_warnings for more information.